# Question got an answer, got changed, got a new answer, got changed back

Tags: discussion

Consider [In C++ objects: Should I be casting pointers with the parent class or should I be casting with the actual class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30062806/2069064). The initial question asked was about `void*`s and got an answer specific to `void*`s. That answer got upvoted, but there was a comment about never using `void*`. OP decided to change the question to *not* use `void*` at all - at which point I chimed in with an answer specific to the new, non-`void*` question that obviated the original answer.

However, before I'd posted my answer, the question was *reverted* to the original question - and shortly thereafter OP accepted my answer to the now-reverted question to which my answer in no way applies. The question is - what to do about this question? Should I just delete my answer (edit: I guess I can't since it's been accepted)?

Comment: I would do Edit/Update/Delete

Comment: As a side thing, what should I have done?  I spotted the question with a non-matching answer, went *huh*, noticed edit, read edit, saw that it rather completely changed the question.  I wrote a comment explaining why it was a bad idea, told the original asked I was going to revert their edit, and did so.  At this point everything looked great.  Had I made any mistakes?  Should I have reverted faster (to reduce the chance a "Barry" would see the intermediate version?) then explained?  Should I have reverted slower, asking the OP to do it for me?  (getting OP buy-in)?  Should I have stayed away?

Comment: @Yakk My understanding at least is that you did the right thing, and I did not :)

Comment: @Barry It isn't "right" in that it leaves the question in a bad, confusing state.  "right" action that fails in when everyone else isn't perfectly "right" isn't very correct.

Comment: Looks OK to me in its present condition.

Comment: @Barry I wouldn't say what you did was bad.  It was a good faith attempt to answer a question you saw.  This just illustrates the problems with changing the nature of a question after it is posted.

Answer (score 22):

Any time an edit would invalidate existing answers, the action to take is to revert it to a point in which the answers aren't invalidated.

So, for this scenario, it seems that [this action has been taken now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30062806/revisions).  Revision 2 caused the radical changes, but you were answering Revision 1.

Revert anything you see like that.  If the offense is repeated several times, then revert and notify a moderator that this is occurring.

Comment: But the situation here is that reverting to either revision would invalidate at least one of the answers that have already been posted.

Comment: I'd tend to suggest editing the answers, to indicate they refer to a different revision of the question.

Comment: When in doubt, I'd err on the side of the first version.

Comment: @makoto he was answering Revision 2, not Revision 1.

Answer (score 18):

The thing to remember with Stack Overflow is that it's not about individual questions - it's about making a really massive FAQ.

Individual supplicants are getting answers as a secondary benefit - the primary purpose is collating unique, good questions and their answers for future reference.

So with that in mind I would suggest:

- Edit your answer, indicating that it is obsolete because of question versioning.  (assuming you can't delete, because it was accepted - maybe flag for moderator attention)

Alternatively:

- revert original post to original question (intent - keep updates, just not the ones that change the meaning).
- open a new question, referencing this post, with the new question content.
- answer that.

(Mark your original post for moderator action)

Comment: +1 Especially for the last suggestion. Makes the most sense imho.

Comment: Question versioning... Now that is an idea! I wonder if the good developers at stack exchange might entertain such a concept, perhaps question history, tabbed with latest at the front?  Therefore always keeping a record of the original, so such confusions may never happen again. Answers could then be linked to versions... Perhaps when clicking / mousing over an answer div, the tab (hence question) changes to that version? A good idea? or over-complicating things?

Comment: You can see edit history. We _shouldn't_ do versioning like that though, because supplicants _shouldn't_ materially alter their initial question. Asking another question is free, and also contributes useful questions/answers to the corpus of knowledge.

Answer (score 10):

Update your answer to include solutions and/or details for:

- using `void*`
- *not* using `void*`
- reasons not to use `void*`

This way your answer (which is accepted) will be valid either way and will have details required to help other users that will visit the question later.